# Hanging Hooks on a Pocket Door Wall

Tags: doors, hardware, drywall-anchor, pocket-door

I have a very small bathroom with extremely limited space and poor planning, and the only place I could put anything to hang two towels is on a narrow sliver of wall next to the shower stall. I’m hoping to install two small, single hooks to hold the weight of one bath towel each. The hooks I got came with small screws, but I don’t think that would hold very well, right? The head measured 1/8”, the length approx. 7/8”.

The problem is that it’s a pocket door wall on the side which the door slides in and out (the drywall side, not the reinforced side with studs).

I’ve only ever used studs or drywall anchors to hang stuff on my walls before, but I don’t think that would be a possibility in this space because I don’t want to scratch the pocket door.

I did my best to measure the gap between the door and the inner drywall area, and it’s 3/4”.
According to Google, the average drywall depth is 1/2” (I don’t know if that’s a standard thickness though).

So it’s:

DOOR - 3/4” gap - 1/2” WALL

Does anyone know what hardware I could use to hang the hooks, with screws that don’t have a larger head that 1/8”?

Apologies for my inexperience, and thanks kindly in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A typical modern pocket door has strips of 3/4” thick struts running horizontally. You’ll be able to see these through the gap when the pocket door is all the way in. Hit these strips with a 1-1/8” screw (keep in mind the hook keeps the screw a little proud of the drywall) and you should be fine. (Test the movement of the door after you’ve driven the screws to make sure, and be prepared to nip the tips, but I doubt that’ll be an issue.)

Answer (score 1):

1/8" isn't going to hold much, neither is just drywall alone.  Some pocket doors are lined with a hardboard, which would help.

Suggestions

1. Screw/nail in a length of timber from one stud to another, spanning the width of the door and mount hooks on it.
2. Use Adhesive hooks such as Command series.

Comment: There really isn’t much in the way of studs to attach to when you have a pocket door.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these.
[image]

The nails are a good length for your situation, the angle creates force against the face of the drywall rather than levering through it, and the small hook reduces the effect of human handling.

It's not ideal, you really shouldn't hang towels on drywall alone, but given your needs I think this will work.